# How to UPDATE properly using $_POST in PHP and mysqli query

Tags: php, post, mysqli, sql-update

So I have this system where you can UPDATE your information and I'm having trouble with it. Right now, when ever i try to update it, there is no error in the code but it gives me a blank result.

Here is my codes in the fill up information:

```
       <?php 
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)) {
        echo "First Name: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$first_name\" name=\"first_name\"><br/>";
        echo "Middle Name: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$middle_name\"><br/>";
        echo "Last Name: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$last_name\"><br/>";
        echo "Age: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$age\"><br/>";
        echo "Remarks: <textarea name=\"remarks\" class=\"form-control\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"6\">";
        echo $remarks;
        echo "</textarea><br/>";
        echo "<center><a href=\"view_all_crew.php\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" >Cancel</button></a>&nbsp;";
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" onclick=\"document.location = 'edit_crew.php?id=$id'; \">Continue</button></center>";
      }
      ?>
```

and here's my code in `update.php` (update query):

```
<?php

    $query_update = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `first_name` = ?, `middle_name` = ?, `last_name` = ?, `age` = ?, `month` = ?, `day` = ?, `year` = ?, `birth_place` = ?, `gender` = ?, `martial_status` = ?, `religion` = ?, `nationality` = ?, `email_address` = ?, `address_1` = ?, `address_2` = ?, `course` = ?, `school_graduated` = ?, `remarks` = ?  WHERE `id` = ?";
    $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query_update);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'sssisiisssssssssssi', $_POST['first_name'], $middle_name, $last_name, $age, $month, $day, $year, $birth_place, $gender, $martial_status, $religion, $nationality, $email_address, $address_1, $address_2, $course, $school_graduated, $remarks, $_GET['id']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);

?>
```

Comment: Did you enable displaying error ? try adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the first line of PHP.

Comment: below the `$query_update`?

Comment: did I mention "first line" ? before `$query_update` of course

Comment: In fact, `mysqli_stmt_execute()` will return whether the query is executed successfully. You didn't echo it out.